# Summing the odd indexes of an array element

Tags: java, arraylist

I have this program, which does a whole heap of stuff but the part i'm having trouble with is summing the odd indexes in an arraylist.

Every 1, 3, 5, 7, etc. I need to sum and add to a variable. The variable is of datatype `BigFraction` and the **ArrayList - knowledge takes BigFractions only**.

So originally I had

```
 //Returns the combined probability (the odd indexes of the arraylist)
public BigFraction weight() {
    BigFraction sum;
    if (knowledge.indexOf(knowledge)%2 == 1)
        sum+ = no idea what to put in here
        return sum;
    }
}
```

I'm really not sure if this is the right syntax for getting indexes of an Arraylist either...  I guess you could use a .add or something too, but if anyone could shed light that would be awesome.

Cheers,

Sim

Comment: For iterating .. for(int i=1, max=list.size(); i<max; i+=2) {

Comment: You want to get the index itself or the value stored at that index ?

Comment: @Ankur - Its highly unlikely that the OP would want to sum the odd indexes.

Comment: sum of values stored at each odd index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out :

```
// Returns the combined probability (the odd indexes of the arraylist)
public BigFraction weight() {
    BigFraction sum;
    for (int index = 1; index < knowledge.size(); index = index + 2) {
        sum = sum.add(knowledge.get(index));
    }

    System.out.println("Sum is  " + sum);

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: You'd have let the OP to atleast give a try on this, before giving the fully baked code.

Comment: that works except I need to change sum+ to sum = sum.add since i have been given another method that adds bigfractions since normal java math does not, on the other hand, .length is unresolved in this case and throwing an error at me

Comment: Ok I got it, cheers I had to initialize sum to BigFraction.ZERO which is basically 0 as a fraction for this particular method, thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint: you already know what the odd indices are. You've listed them in your question. All you have to do is find a way to *loop* over them.

Once you've figured that out, you'll need to find a way to *get* the element at the given index.

The rest, I am sure, will be easy.

Comment: I tried using a for loop before, didn't work so well, maybe i'll try again